# libGDX - Why do I have to use camera.setToOrtho what does it do?

Tags: java, libgdx, camera, projection, projection-matrix

I am very confused about camera matrices and I don't know where to start my studying. Maybe I have to study OpenGL, but I don't know C++ ...

Ok so I have a camera, Box2d world and a Box2d body.

```
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private Body player;

@Override
public void create () {
    //Create the world without gravity
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), false);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    //I create my camera
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();

    //Create the player
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    //Sets the body position to the center of the screen
    bdef.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

    player = world.createBody(bdef);
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(2f);
    player.createFixture(shape, 1f);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    world.step(1f/60f, 6, 2);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    b2dr.render(world, cam.combined);
}
```

I am not seeing the player on the center of the screen, just a black void.

But if I add cam.setToOrtho(false); I see the player!
Why is that?

setToOrtho sets the camera to Orthographic projection WHY?

The camera is Orthographic what oder projection can it have?? Isn't the orthographic projection obvious?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html#setToOrtho-boolean-), `setToOrtho` is _not_ about setting it ortho or not ortho, it's about where does the y axis points: up or down.

Comment: Both  setToOrtho(false) and setToOrtho(true) work, so that shouldn't be the case...

Comment: Well maybe the important part is _"Sets this camera to an orthographic projection using a viewport fitting the screen resolution, centered at (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)"_. Not sure, though, I'm not an expert in libGDX.

Comment: My question is more general... I want to know why I have to set an Orthographic camera to orthographic projection, isn't this by default? I mean what oder projection can an orthographic camera have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setToOrtho` does not set the projection type of the camera. An `OrthographicCamera` will always have an orthographic frustrum.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.java), it seems to me that `setToOrtho` is a convenience method to set the viewport size to the screen size and center the camera on the viewport. `setToOrtho(false)` is showing your character is because your character is within this default viewport that `setToOrtho` creates.

The reason why you can't see your character without this call, is you never give your camera a viewport size and you never update the camera. Try

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

And then every time you change any parameters of your camera, you must call  `cam.update();` before any draw calls. I usually end up changing the camera so often that I call this every frame.

Comment: You are right, thanks man! setToOrtho() has very confusing documentation for me...